# Check Disabled Checkbox

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to check if a checkbox is checked but, I suppose that as it is disabled, it always returns false. It's disabled because I only use it to show the option is set to the user (I modify it via Ajax). How can I check the real value? Nothing works.

```php
<?php

dd(isset($_POST['bolMensual']));
dd(!empty($_POST['bolMensual']));
dd($request->has('bolMensual'));

if ($request->has('bolMensual')) {
    $bolMensual = $request->input('bolMensual');

    if ($this->validateDate($request->input('datFecha'), 'Y-m')) {
        $datMesAplica = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', $request->input('datFecha'));
        dd($datMesAplica);
    } else {
        return back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Fecha incorrecta');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried un-disabling it before you call your ajax, getting the value, re-disabling it, and using the value you got from it in your ajax? It would be beneficial if we could see your ajax as well...

Comment: Actually,  the ajax don't have to be in the process, it's used in a drop down to set the check box value, I mean, I only menctioned it because it's the way the check box get a value, even when it's disabled. I try to get the value at submit button. The piece of code above is at the controller, when the user clicks the submit button.